# Descriptions of tag-based badges are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, badges

The descriptions associated to tag-based badges are wrong, they always show `0` instead of actual thresholds:

> Earned at least **0** total score for at least **0** non-community wiki answers in the … tag

[See few examples by using the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#order=desc&sort=rank&inname=python-3&filter=!9WA%28%28Mcf3&site=stackoverflow&run=true). See [more examples](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=rank&filter=!9WA%28%28Mcf3&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: 7 months and nobody fixed? Is there any way to contact someone like a developer or something?

Comment: Thanks for the update @BrockAdams, I checked a few months ago and there were still `0`, the number are correct now. Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been silently/magically fixed in the last 7 months (Date of  Nicos Karalis' comment).

Descriptions seem correct now. I had verified that they weren't correct when I upvoted this question on Apr 29 '14.

---

Side note: It's not documented, but apparently **tag-based badges are not listed unless they have been awarded at least once.**

[Take a look at `/2.2/badges?inname=python-3&site=stackoverflow`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#order=desc&sort=name&inname=python-3&filter=!9YdnSNaMz&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

```
//-- "link" and "badge_id" lines removed for clarity/space.
{
  "items": [
    {
      "badge_type": "tag_based",
      "award_count": 2,
      "rank": "gold",
      "description": "Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the <a href=\"/questions/tagged/python-3.x\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;python-3.x&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">python-3.x</a> tag",
      "name": "python-3.x"
    }, {
      "badge_type": "tag_based",
      "award_count": 14,
      "rank": "silver",
      "description": "Earn at least 400 total score for at least 80 non-community wiki answers in the <a href=\"/questions/tagged/python-3.x\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;python-3.x&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">python-3.x</a> tag",
      "name": "python-3.x"
    }, {
      "badge_type": "tag_based",
      "award_count": 89,
      "rank": "bronze",
      "description": "Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the <a href=\"/questions/tagged/python-3.x\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;python-3.x&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">python-3.x</a> tag",
      "name": "python-3.x"
    }, {
      "badge_type": "tag_based",
      "award_count": 1,
      "rank": "bronze",
      "description": "Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the <a href=\"/questions/tagged/python-3.4\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;python-3.4&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">python-3.4</a> tag",
      "name": "python-3.4"
    }, {
      "badge_type": "tag_based",
      "award_count": 1,
      "rank": "bronze",
      "description": "Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the <a href=\"/questions/tagged/python-3.3\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;python-3.3&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">python-3.3</a> tag",
      "name": "python-3.3"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
}
```

Note that there are no silver or gold badges listed for either `python-3.3` or `python-3.4`.
And these badges [haven't been](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.3/topusers) [earned yet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.4/topusers).